# Serialise JSON object

Tags: json, vb.net

I have asked this before but have not been able to get the answer can anyone help please?  The json string below is produced using jquery,  I need to produce the same string using vb.net I have attempted to convert the string using Json2csharp (then convert this to vb.net) but get the class object with invalid names returned. How do you construct a class that will cope with the '$gte' and '$date' parameters?

JSON:

```
{ "driver" : "Driver", "_createdAt":{"$gte":{"$date":"2013-11-01T11:36:35.151Z"}}}
```

Json2csharp conversation

```
public class Gte
{
    public string __invalid_name__$date { get; set; }
}

public class CreatedAt
{
    public Gte __invalid_name__$gte { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string driver { get; set; }
    public CreatedAt _createdAt { get; set; }
}
```

### EDIT

Hi, thanks for your pointers I have now got the code as in the sample below which returns the JSON:

```
{"driver":"JBOHEN","_createdAt":{"$gte":"2013-11-23T10:44:58.667Z"}}
```

How would I construct the class so that the JSON includes the date operator as in?

```
{"driver " : "Driver", "_createdAt":{"$gte":{"$date":"2013-11-01T11:36:35.151Z"}}} 

public class Gte
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$date")]
    public string date { get; set; }
}

public class CreatedAt
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$gte")]
    public string gte { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string driver { get; set; }
    public CreatedAt _createdAt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you are open to [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/). You can try `JsonPropertyAttribute`

Comment: I have used JSON.Net for basic operations (serializing, de serializing) I have looked at the documentation but can't find any examples of using JsonPropertyAttribut do you have any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **JsonPropertyAttribute**

> Instructs the JsonSerializer to always serialize the member with the specified name.

You can decorate your property which you want controlg its name with the `[JsonProperty]` attribute which allows you to specify a different name:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$date")]
public string date { get; set; }
```

[**Official Docs**](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationAttributes.htm)

### EDIT

Construct classes as

```
public class Gte
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$date")]
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}

public class CreatedAt
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$gte")]
    public Gte gte { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string driver { get; set; }
    public CreatedAt _createdAt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Satpal,  Thanks for that I now get the JSON in the correct syntax.

Comment: hi i do this with '[JsonProperty("name")' but vs2012 doesn't recognize '[JsonProperty',   it says 'Bracketted identifier missing closing bracket ]',  How do i fix this?

Comment: @f1wade, You need to use `[JsonProperty("name")]`, You are missing closing `]`